# django delete model in admin site - 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

When I try to delete a model in the admin panel, I get this error.
I can not find where the problem is.

> TypeError at /admin/account/cloud/1/delete/
>
> 'bool' object is not callable

- [admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnROy.png)
- [Error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgoV7.png)

django: 1.10.6

postgres: 9.5.6

OS: Ubuntu server 16.04

Model with problem:

```
class Cloud(models.Model):
    NAME_CHOICE = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4')
    )
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, verbose_name='Аккаунт')
    name = models.CharField(choices=NAME_CHOICE, verbose_name='Название', max_length=20, default=NAME_CHOICE[0][0])
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='Пользовательское название', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Активный?', default=False)
    params = JSONField(verbose_name='Параметры', null=True, blank=True)
    delete = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Удален?', default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'ID: {}, облако: {}'.format(self.id, (self.username or '-'))
```

INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'account',
    'api',
    'cell',
    'files',

    'deploy_frontend',
    'rest_framework',
    # 'rest_framework_docs',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
]
```

**How obj can be "bool", if obj = cloud-object?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `obj.delete` is a `BooleanField` according to your model definition rather than the [default `delete` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects). You may want to give the field a different name, like `is_deleted`.

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very mach!

Answer (score 2):

**At Django 2** this problem can also occur when your *foreignkey model field* set `on_delete=True`.

swap `on_delete=True` for `on_delete=models.CASCADE` or `on_delete=models.PROTECT` or `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` or `on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT` or `on_delete=models.SET()`

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Comment: Thanks.  on_delete=models.CASCADE  worked for me